# When to switch from struct to class in swift?

Tags: swift, class, struct, swift-protocols

I am thinking on this for hours:
Lets say you have a generic game. The game can have players and an methode that sets a score. This can be done by using a protocol:

```swift
protocol Game {
    var players: [Player] {get set}
    func setScore (for player: Player, value: Int)
    func sendSomeMessage(message: String)

}
```

i can now create a struct confirming to the protocol "Game"

```swift
struct raiseGame: Game {
    var players: [Player]()
    func setScore (for player: Player, value: Int) {
        player.score += value
    }
    func sendSomeMessage(message: String) {
       players.forEach { player in
            //send the message to each player
       }
    }
}
```

But then i have, lets say, another struct conforming to Game. But in this time the score should be decreased. All other things stay the same. Now i have to write all the code for the func sendSomeMessage again. (There could be many more functions which stays the same).

The question is now: Should i switch to a class, write a base class and inherit from it, or is there a way to provide somekind of default implementations for functions in protocols, so i don't need to write them every time again, when confirming to a protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to provide somekind of default implementations for functions in protocols, so i don't need to write them every time again, when confirming to a protocol?

There is indeed a way to provide default method implementations for protocol-conforming types:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
    func myMethodRequirement()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func myMethodRequirement() {
        // Default implementation.
    }
}

struct Foo: MyProtocol {
    func myMethodRequirement() {
        // Foo-specific implementation.
    }
}

struct Bar: MyProtocol {
    /* Inherits default implementation instead. */
}
```

In your case, giving `sendSomeMessage(message:)` a default implementation would look like:

```swift
extension Game {
    func sendSomeMessage(message: String) {
        // Default implementation here.
    }
}
```

Any type conforming to `Game` could either implement `sendSomeMessage(message:)` itself (similar to `override`-ing a method in a class), or use the default implementation without doing any additional work.

For more information, you can see the ["Providing Default Implementations" section on protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID529) of the The Swift Programming Language guide.

---

To answer the *title* of your question, then, given that it is possible to do this for `struct`s:

- A `class` may be useful over a `struct` if you have an inheritance hierarchy multiple levels deep, which may be more complicated to express using protocol conformances
- A `class` may be useful over a `struct` when you need reference semantics — see:

  - [Structures and Enumerations are Value Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html#ID88) and
  - [Classes are Reference Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html#ID89)

In your specific case, it doesn't immediately appear that either of these apply, but with more information, it might become obvious whether switching would be beneficial or not.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted to know! In my current case i can stay on a struct. No need to switch to a class. And thank your for your detailed answer. :)

Comment: @gegy Excellent! Happy to have helped :)